# Fetch data on-demand in VueJS (vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, lazy-initialization

I have a store with some data that is used by multiple components:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        _invoices: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setInvoices: (state, invoices) => (state._invoices = invoices),
    },
    actions: {
        getInvoices: context => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const invoices = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
                // mimicking ajax call
                context.commit('setState', invoices);
            },2000);
        },
    },
})
```

In my component I call `$store.dispatch('getInvoices')` to actually fetch them.

Is there a way to fetch invoices automatically (i.e. without manually calling the `getInvoices` from inside the component), but only when the invoices are actually requested?

e.g. if a user logged in just to change his password and never goes on the component that requires invoices, they're not loaded.

as I mentioned, multiple components require invoices, so I'd like to avoid putting `$store.dispatch('getInvoices')` in every component's `mounted()` method.

any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: could show main.js and some components code ?

Comment: that's a lot of code, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: one of your components and `main.js`

Answer (score 3):

## You can use Navigation Guards if you are using Vue Router

Use `router.beforeEach()` if you are using Vue Router.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Use middleware if you are using Nuxt.js, but technically, middleware is same as navigation guard.
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware

Comment: This is really bad idea. It brings more mess than is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a mixin that calls `$store.dispatch('getInvoices')` on the `mounted` hook. Then use that mixin in every component that needs to fetch invoices.

Comment: Well then consider creating a [Global Mixin that injects a custom option](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin)

Comment: that would add this call to every single component throughout the entire application...

Comment: True but it would only be called when you provide the custom option in the component you want to use it in. And it would be clear up there in the component's definition, not buried in your `mounted` hook.